# Unable to generate new token using JWT method (C#)

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I downloaded the sample code (jwt-framework) from GitHub and watch video from "Larry Kluger". When I run code, it throws exception and the error message as follows.
Error raises from ApiClient.RequestJWTUserToken method calling.

**Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Error with response** 
I did all steps according to the Larry's video.

1. clientid(Integration key)
2. UserId
3. Private Key of RSA
4. Redirect Uri

I saw the details comments under exception block. Error message does not contain "consent_required". However, according to the video and blogs. I used the following code to get AuthorizationUri and put the browser and did accept.

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=xxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com

I tried both "Authorization Code Grand" and "Implicit Grand" settings in Sandbox and change response_type respectively in url.

Page show username and login. after successfully login, I clicked "Accept" button. After that it goes to  a different page.

Finally, I ran my code but still I am getting the same error.

I am not clear what is the issue. If anyone knows, please give me the details that I can resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common reasons:

1. RSA Key is not copy/pasted correctly. It must be *exactly* like you had it, with the correct end of lines and nothing different. How do you store it in your code?
2. No Consent. The specific user must consent at least once. You have to see the name of your integration and consent to it. And you should have asked for both sign and impersonate scopes.

If you can confirm 1 and 2 first, as these are the most common reasons.

Comment: Hi Hi, how can I help?

Comment: Thanks Inbar for your answer.  1. I copied RSA private key from DocuSign Developer Sandbox and pasted into a text file. I read file converted to byte[] and passed to RetrieveJWTUserToken() method. I also tried copy the key and put string variable and convert to byte[] and tried.  2. Not clear your question.   But when i use Authorization Uri i used scope=signature%20impersonation. Actually, I am new about DocuSign api.  Would you clear me #2 question.

Comment: go to https://account-d.docusign.com/me/#/appconsent, click "Connected Apps" and see if you app (what you named your integration key) shows in there (make sure to login with the same user that you want to use, where you got the userID GUID from)

Comment: I see my test app name("Dev Docusign API"). I myself as an admin user and use my GUID userId as impersonateUser.  I also created a new RSA key and copy/paste the private key to a new text file.   Again first time I got the same error and when I use "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth? … " to AuthorizationUri, it goes to "https://www.docusign.com/?code= xxx ". Finally, when I run the application again to get token, I am getting same error.

Comment: The code which I use as follows: var key = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\RSAPrivate_Key.txt");
 OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(DSConfig.ClientID,DSConfig.ImpersonatedUserGuid,  DSConfig.AuthServer,  key, 1); . I could not figure out the issue.

Comment: Try to clone this repo - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp and configure the json configuration file (copy the demo one into a real one) and see if you can get that to work with your IK and Key. If it does - it's a code issues, if it doesn't - it's a configuration issue. Good way to isolate the problem.

Comment: Hi Inbar. Thank you for your comment and proper source code link. I downloaded the code and change setup and run,it works.

Comment: I have another question about consent. I tested with individual consent for grant. How can I setup grant consent on behalf of a  domain users/ users list to an internal application? I do not want to individual consent one time for each user. Do I need to change in code or settings?  Please let me know.

Comment: can you mark this question as answered? the consent question is different. Let me share a link with some information
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent#:~:text=Although%20the%20DocuSign%20Admin%20panel,are%20owned%20by%20your%20organization).

Comment: Hi Inbar. Thank you to provide the link. I read the document. I tried to set up "Admin consent for internal applications" but i do not see the options in my DocuSign eSignature Admin panel sandbox. Is DocuSign Administration panel different then   DocuSign eSignature Admin panel? Please let me know where can i get those options to setup.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the name is in flux, but there's only one admin panel

Comment: Hi Inbar. Thanks for your cooperation. I read document "org-admin-guid.pdf", and link which you sent before to set up Admin consent. I do not see the option of "Connected App" (To authorize an application for all domain users) in the left panel of my admin dashboard. We have a user developer@companyname.com and has admin permission. I would like to share my admin page screenshot to verify anything wrong. How can I send my admin page screenshot? would you please give your email address?

Comment: inbar.gazit@docusign.com